# Скрыть видимость учетной записи

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Добрый день, при входе в Win отображаются две учетной записи, есть ли возможность скрыть одну средствами c# не отключая или не удаляя её.

Comment: С помощью C# можно сделать то же самое, что и с помощью любого другого языка, имеющего доступ к WinAPI. И теперь ключевой вопрос: как вы хотите скрыть учётную запись, не скрывая её на уровне системы, и чего вообще вы хотите добиться?

Comment: просто что бы она не отображалась при входе в win

Answer (score 5):

1. Запустите `regedit`.
2. Откройте `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
3. Создание новый ключ с именем `SpecialAccounts`.
4. В `SpecialAccounts` создайте новый ключ с именем `UserList`.
5. В `UserList` создайте новое значение с типом `DWORD (32bit) Value`, именем - **имя того пользователя, которе вы хотите спрятать** и значением `0`.

Это [официально задокументированный метод для прятанья (и отображения) аккаунтов](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942956) начиная с Vista и старше. 
Из C# то же самое можно проделать c помощью классов из [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Даже так — официальный метод? Куда катится мир?

Answer (score 2):

Можно настроить автоматический вход, тогда экран приветствия не будет отображаться. Реестр надо править: http://winzone.com.ru/windows-xp/ustanovka-i-zagruzka-winxp/15-avtomaticheskiy-vhod-polzovatelya-windows.html